# How to make a surface meshlike

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a surface that has mesh (net) lines in the plot such that one can see(trace) exactly corresponding values for some fixed values from any of the axes. An example below is a code what I have done but that is not what I want. Is it possible to have a black (or any color) mesh lines embedded on a surface plot to easy tracing of some fixed values?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def fun(x, y):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x-y))

n=400
x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, n)
y = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax[0,0].plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=40, cstride=40)
ax[0,1].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=40, cstride=40, color='m')
ax[1,0].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=12, cstride=12, cmap='coolwarm')
ax[1,1].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=20, cstride=20, cmap=cm.hot)

for axes in ax.flatten():
    axes.set_xticks([-3,-2, -1, 0, 1, 2,3])
    axes.set_yticks([-3,-2, -1, 0, 1, 2,3])
    axes.set_zticks([0, 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8, 1])
fig.tight_layout()

#cbar= fig.colorbar(surf,hrink=0.5, aspect=12)
plt.show()
```

This is the

[image: output].

As you can see there are four plots and based on the 'rstride'and 'cstride' choosen I get some form of net or mesh on the surface

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to have the mesh embedded in the plot

Comment: welcome @BDG to SO. If any answer solved your problem, please accept it as an answer or upvote if it is helpful; Don't use comments like *thanks* and …. As you mentioned in a comment below *JeffUK's answer*, he answered your question truly. So, accept it as the answer if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can over-lay the wireframe on the surface,  e.g.:

```
ax[0,1].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=40, cstride=40, color='m')
ax[0,1].plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=40, cstride=40, color='k', linewidth=0.5)
```

[image: Picture of result 1]

You can also do it a couple of times with different widths to get major and minor lines. (which also looks cool)

```
ax[1,1].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=20, cstride=20, cmap=cm.hot)
ax[1,1].plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=20, cstride=20, color='k', linewidth=0.5)
ax[1,1].plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=100, cstride=100, color='k', linewidth=1.0)
```

[image: Result of example 2]